# Calling a method inside of itself

Tags: java, methods, rss, sax

Im trying to make an rss reader, where this particulair piece of code is attempting to call itself. Im following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ezR_FezlVxQ&t=299s). Now, the tutorial is from 2012, so im probably just using something that doesnt work since its outdated. But i still want to find a solution. Any help?

code in question:

```
public List<RssItem> getItems() throws Exception {
    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
    RssParserHandler handler = new RssParserHandler();
    saxParser.parse(rssUrl, handler);
    return handler.getItems();
}
```

The handler.getItems(); shows up as an error.

Comment: Which error does it show ?

Comment: Technically, those are two different methods (one from each of two different classes) with the same name.

Comment: @AnandUndavia "Cannot resolve method "getItems()""

Comment: Is this code from the class `RssParserHandler`? If not, did you import `RssParserHandler`?